# Alloc and init in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, init, alloc

Maybe this is a dumb question, but I really want to figure this one out.

For example I have the following setup:

```
// .h
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
   NSView *myView;
}

// .m

@implementation MyClass

-(void)someMethod
{

   // WHAT IS THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THIS
   myView = [[NSView alloc] init];

   // AND THIS ?

   myView = [myView init]; // assuming that myView was allocated somewhere earlier in init method
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` methods tend to assume that you only send `init` once to every object.

Sending `init` *again* to a previously-allocated-and-initialized `myView` will break this assumption, causing memory leaks and possibly subsequent weird behavior. Both result from your second `init` message to `myView` creating objects, adding observers, etc. that the same object had already set up before.

That's what the second line in `someMethod` does.

The first line creates a new view, this being the impact of the `alloc`/`init` one-two punch. This view is a different object from the view you entered `someMethod` with (if any), so sending `init` to that object as part of its creation is not a problem.

Remember: the object is not the variable. `myView` is the name of the variable; when we say “`myView`”, we really mean “the object that `myView` holds”.

(It may be a good idea to re-read this answer from the top with the concept from the last paragraph firmly in mind.)

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you Peter! I have another follow up question. What if I want to change the contents of a view object? For example:    NSView *iv = arrOfSubvs[0]; 
            iv = [iv initWithFrame:[[[self playerView] layer] bounds]];     - so I want to grab particular view that is sitting in the array and change its contents, is the second line a valid thing to do or it introduces some negative effect?

Comment: @EugeneGordin: It's invalid, for the same reasons why doing the same thing with `init` is invalid. Any initializer (`init…`) message should only be sent to each object no more than once. This is why `alloc` and `init` is written as a one-two punch: you initialize it then, literally in the same line in which you allocated it, and never again because you never do it separately.

Answer (score 1):

This statement `myView = [[NSView alloc] init];` is just a nested method call to this following

```
NSView *myView =[NSView alloc]; //line 1
myView=[myView init];//line 2
```

If you do it in a single line or in multiple lines it doesn't do any thing specific.

line 1 : here a new memory location is `alloc`ated for the object.

line 2 : An `init` is sent to the object, to initialize the object.

Comment: That doesn't answer what the effect is of doing line 2 without line 1, as shown in the question.

Comment: @PeterHosey: He mentioned in comments that `alloc` is done somewhere else, so alloc + init in 2 lines, this is what I understood and answered.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C differs from many other object-oriented languages in making object creation an explicit two stage process, *allocation* and *initialisation*.

If you are familiar with languages such as Java, C# and C++ then the allocation part of object creation is indivisible from initialisation. So for example in Java you might write:

```
class Tree {

// constructor/initialiser
public Tree ()
{
   // whatever is needed to initialise a Tree
}

}

...
Tree myTree = new Tree(); // allocate and initalise a tree
```

Java's `new` expression *allocates* memory for a `Tree` and then invokes the constructor to setup up that memory correctly.

The above languages are recognising that allocation and initialisation are just two parts of what is really a single operation: object creation.

In Objective-C the above example would be:

```
@implementation Tree

// constructor/initialiser
(id) init ()
{
   // whatever is needed to initialise a Tree
}

@end

...
Tree *myTree = [[Tree alloc] init]; // allocate and initalise a tree
```

Here you could *in theory* separate the allocation and the initialization but that is not to be advised. The reason for this is `[Tree alloc]` doesn't usually return a fully formed `Tree`, it allocates some memory and marks it as a `Tree` but any instance variables owned by `Tree`, or the super classes of `Tree` are *not* initialised - to do the initialisation `init` must be called. If you separate the two operations then you potentially have incomplete objects lying around which will not behave as expected. So though you *can* separate them doing so is so unwise that Apple's documentation for `init` states:

> An `init` message is coupled with an `alloc` message in the same line of code

That is Apple tells a small untruth to prevent you making a big mistake.

Objective-C does also provide a single operation form of creation:

```
Tree *myTree = [Tree new]; // alloc + init
```

However unlike Java *et al* if you write an initializer which takes arguments you don't get automatically get a version of `new` which takes arguments - you need to write that yourself (as a class method using `alloc` and the initializer which takes the arguments).

HTH